# Deleting zero rows and columns in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays

How do i delete zero columns in python?

I figured out how to delete the rows with the code `array[~(array==0).all(1)]` and I thought i could simply write `array[~(array==0).all(0)]` to delete the columns but this gives me an error (boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 4 but corresponding boolean dimension is 6). Why is that?

Comment: `array[:, ~(array==0).all(0)]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `~(array==0).all(0)` will give you a mask for which *columns* to keep.

E.g.

```
>>> array
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0]])
>>> ~(array==0).all(0)
array([ True,  True, False])
```

So you just need to apply the mask to the array's second axis.

Hence,

```
>>> array[:,~(array==0).all(0)]
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help-

```
import numpy as np
dataset = np.array([[ 5, 8, 0], [ 1, 2, 0]])
dataset

>> array([[5, 0, 0],
      [1, 2, 0]])
```

let's delete

```
new_dataset= np.delete(dataset,np.where(~dataset.any(axis=0))[0], axis=1)
new_dataset

>>
array([[5, 0],
   [1, 2]])
```

Only deleting when the whole column is 0.

Comment: Thank you. This might actually be an easier way of doing it than mine.